# I commented jquery-ui.min.js to show a modal window but this is restricting to show datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog

I have a html page  as below 
`

```html
<HTML lang="EN-US">

<HEAD>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />


  <TITLE>
    DUMMY
  </TITLE>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel=stylesheet href=styles.css>


</HEAD>

<body class="mild-blue">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <metatags id="MetaTags1" selectedtabindex="0" runat="server" />


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      wp.include("menu");
    </script>


  </head>
  <!--Confirm Modal to naviagate to APP-->
  <div id="navigateConfirm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <form>
        <div class="modal-content warning-block">
          <div class="header">
            <h6>Confirmation</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <p class="d-inline-block my-md-2 mt-0 medium p-0">You are navigating out of iStore. Any pending changes will be lost. Continue ?</p>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="button-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" id="navigateConfirmYes">YES</button>
              <button type="submit" class="button-primary" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <head>


    <div class="primary-header">
      <nav class="row navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex">
          <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" id="navigateAPP" />
          <p class="header p-0" onclick="#">TEST Store</p>
        </a>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript">
      $("#navigateAPP").click(function(event) {
        $('#navigateConfirm').modal('show');
      });

      $("#navigateConfirmYes").click(function(event) {
        window.location.href = document.getElementById("returnUrl").value;
      });
    </script>


    <div class="row m-0">
      <div class="col-lg-6 deliveryOps p-0 pr-lg-1">
        <div class="cartCard py-3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="formField mb-0 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">

              <input type="text" name="ibeforedate" id="ibeforedate" class="datepicker" placeholder="Example: 31-DEC-1999" autocomplete="off" required onChange="this.value = datecheck(this.value,'DD-MON-RRRR');" readonly>

              <label class="input_label medium">Request Delivery Date</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`

When user clicks on logo.svg, navigateAPP modal window should popup
at the same we have one datefield.

Now the issue is, if i use  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
I am able to open date calendar and select the date from the calender. But when i click on logo.svg, navigateAPP modal window is not appearing.

When i uncomment the jquery-ui.js, able to see modal window but datepicker is not working.

How to make both the things work.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Manjula, would you be able to update your question with some example code to demonstrate the order you are loading these scripts in?

Comment: Updated the qn with sample code.